# Can bones made of carbon exist?

Tags: evolution, xenobiology

I'm looking for an alternative way for creatures of an alien planet to evolve bones without using calcium, so I thought an easy(?) way  would be to have their bones made out of a carbon polymer, as there is plenty of carbon in the planet.
Would there be a way for rigid bones to be made out of such a compound, if so, how?

Comment: Wood is a carbon based polymer and has proven being quite sturdy. What does it miss that doesn't satisfy your question?

Comment: If your intention is to completely remove calcium from the environment (although I'm not sure why you'd want that), you should be aware it has [many other biological roles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcium_in_biology) besides bone formation.

Comment: Similar question: [Would carbon fiber be a good choice to strengthen human bones, and how would that work?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/126606/40609)

Answer (score 1):

The exoskeletons of arthropods are made of chitin (C8H13O5N), which is a sturdy material. Wood is made primarily of cellulose (C6H10O5) and similar, simpler compounds. Both of these materials have proven sturdy.

Comment: Cartilage is another important material made up primarily of carbon-based polymers, and it's sturdy enough to serve as the skeleton for cartilaginous fish such as sharks. But while all three of these can be durable, none of them are *as durable as* bone.